# Node - How can a script be sure of the location of a dependency to call?

Tags: node.js, npm, prettier

We are developing an `npm package`, a library, that is going to be included in other projects. This package sometimes has to run a shell script: it calls [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) using *`${somePath}/node_modules/prettier/bin/prettier.js`* with some parameters.

The problem is that, because of the way `node_modules` is generated, the location of that `prettier.js` script doesn't seem to be guaranteed. It may be directly under the `node_module` folder of the package, for example :

```
mainProject/node_modules/ourNpmPackage/node_modules/prettier/bin/prettier.js
```

or it can be moved by npm to the root `node_module` folder :

```
mainProject/node_modules/prettier/bin/prettier.js
```

Our script has to know the location of this `.js` to call it! What is the recommended way of locating it?

Would it be possible to first check in the local `node_modules`, then, if `prettier` is not found, in the parent's `node_modules`, etc until the package is found? Would this be a solid solution?

Comment: You should not take any assumptions about the structure of the `node_modules` hierarchy. If possible you should use something like `require('prettier/bin/prettier.js')` which should resolve to the file you are looking for.

Comment: @t.niese We launch our script using a variation of `execFile(...)`. How can this `require` help us finding the location of the target file? Thanks.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the link, it seems `require.resolve('module');` is the solution!

Comment: Some modules export a function in the bin script that allows to call them with the command line arguments. Otherwise you can use the linked duplicate to get the path.

Comment: Using `execFile` on a `bin/*.js` is in most cases just a work around. Normally all module should provide a simple ways to use is as if it was called form command line. And you should always prefere an API solution over the the `exeFile` solution.